# TPOT: Pickling Error When Using TPOTRegressor

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tpot

I have a DataFrame called `X` and a set of target values called `Y`.

For most of my models, I do something like this (just an example):

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LassoCV
clf = LassoCV()
score = cross_val_score(estimator = clf, X = X, y = Y, cv = KFold(n_splits = 3, random_state = 100), n_jobs = -1, \
                        scoring = "neg_mean_squared_error")
np.mean([np.sqrt(-x) for x in score])
```

I'm trying to use TPOT in a similar way, as follows:

```
from tpot import TPOTRegressor
tpot = TPOTRegressor(generations=20, population_size=100, verbosity=2)

score = cross_val_score(estimator = tpot, X = X, y = Y, cv = KFold(n_splits = 3, random_state = 100), n_jobs = -1, \
                        scoring = "neg_mean_squared_error")
np.mean([np.sqrt(-x) for x in score])
```

TPOT starts up but then gives me a pickling error as follows:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: it's not found as __builtin__.instancemethod
```

Any idea why this is happening / how to get TPOT to play nicely?

Thanks!

Comment: what about clf =TPOTClassifier(generations=5, population_size=20, cv=5,
                                    random_state=42, verbosity=2) instead of using regression.then using clf.score(X_test, y_test)

Comment: @Mr_U4913 I should be using TPOTRegressor, I believe, since it's a regression problem

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 2,
try:

```
import dill
```

So that lambda functions can be pickled.... Worked for me...

in Python 3, you might need:

```
import dill as pickle
```

Comment: this did not worked for me: still say: PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'tpot.operator_utils.GradientBoostingRegressor__alpha'>: it's not found as tpot.operator_utils.GradientBoostingRegressor__alpha

Answer (score 1):

Try using: **tpot.fitted_pipeline_**

```
from tpot import TPOTRegressor
tpot = TPOTRegressor(generations=20, population_size=100, verbosity=2)

score = cross_val_score(estimator = tpot.fitted_pipeline_, X = X, y = Y, cv = KFold(n_splits = 3, random_state = 100), n_jobs = -1, \
                        scoring = "neg_mean_squared_error")
np.mean([np.sqrt(-x) for x in score])
```